# Unable to get the value (selected option) of select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form contains among others several select elements.

With a function I would like to retrieve the value of 3 of those select elements which I need for a if else if loop.

I checked if I get the values of those 3 select elements and strangely, it returns only the value of the first select element.

No clue why, need some advice here, thanks. Marc

**Function in a js file :**

```
document.addEventListener('load', switchPrice, true); function switchPrice() {
    var d1 = $('#producttypeID').val(); // producttypeID
    console.log('producttype ID:', d1);
    var d2 = $('productname').val(); // productnameID
    console.log('product ID:', d2);
    var d3 = $('#dessertservingID').val(); // dessertservingID
    console.log('Servings:', d3);
    etc.
}
```

**Console log return :**

```
producttype ID: 1
priceswitch.js:15 product ID: 
priceswitch.js:17 Servings:
```

and no error.

**HTML :**

producttype ID :

```
<select class="form-control" id="producttypeID" data-value="1" disabled="" name="producttypeID" required="">
    <option value="">** Please choose</option>
    <option selected="" value="1">One</option>
    <option value="4">Two</option>
    <option value="2">Three</option>
    <option value="3">Four</option>
</select>
```

product ID :

```
<select class="form-control" id="productname" data-value="1" name="productname" required="">
    <option value="">** Please choose</option>
    <option selected="" value="1">Product 1</option>
    <option value="2">Product 2</option>
    <option value="3">Product 3</option>
    <option value="4">Product 4</option>
    <option value="5">Product 5</option>
    <option value="6">Product 6</option>
    <option value="7">Product 7</option>
    <option value="8">Product 8</option>
    <option value="9">Product 9</option>
    <option value="10">Product 10</option>
    <option value="11">Product 11</option>
    <option value="13">Product 12</option>
    <option value="14">Product 13</option>
    <option value="12">Product 14</option>  
</select>
```

Servings :

```
<select class="form-control" id="dessertservingID" data-value="11" name="dessertservingID" required="">
        <option value="">** Please choose</option>
        <option value="7">10-12 pers.</option>
        <option value="8">12-14 pers.</option>
        <option value="9">14-16 pers.</option>
        <option value="10">16-18 pers.</option>
        <option value="1">2-3 pers.</option>
        <option selected="" value="11">20-24 pers.</option>
        <option value="2">3-4 pers.</option>
        <option value="3">4-6 pers.</option>
        <option value="4">5-7 pers.</option>
        <option value="5">6-8 pers.</option>
        <option value="6">8-10 pers.</option>
</select>
```

**What I have already tried :**

```
    var d2 = $('productname').val();

    var d2 = $('#productname').children('option:selected').val();

    var d2 = $('#productname :selected').val();

    var d2 = document.getElementById('productname').selectedIndex;

    var d2 = document.getElementById('productname').options[document.getElementById('productname').selectedIndex].value;

    var e = document.getElementById('productname');
    var d2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var d2 = $('#productname').val();

    var select_id = document.getElementById('productname');
    var d2 = select_id.options[select_id.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution : Need to run after the page is loaded :

Changed :

```
document.addEventListener('load', switchPrice, true); function switchPrice() {

with

$(window).bind('load', function() {
```

adios

Answer (score 0):

The value of the select should be accessible directly on the select element like this:

```
$('#productname')[0].value
```

Try something like this if you want to catch it as it changes:

```
$('#productname').on('change', function(e){
console.log(e.target.value); // should print the value of the selected option
})
```

Does that help?
Here's a link to a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/itamark/pd647cgo/7/

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the value is returned with your function, I tried with the second select and it works too. how can I get this value into a var

Comment: By the way the value isn't changing since the select is disabled and just need to show the value previously chosen.

Comment: @marcq you can see in my fiddle I show you how to get the initial `selected` value. You need to take the jQuery element's first index value `$('#productname')[0].value`. Does that help?